# Random function in Django template shows "Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'random()"

Tags: django, django-templates

I am developing a site in django web framework. I am aiming to use random function in my template. But it gives an error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'random()'.

My code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="justrandom-{{ random() }} actualid-{{ comment.id }}">
```

I don't know what I did wrong. Obviously, if I don't use random(), template is working fine.

Do I have to import something to use random function in template?

Comment: This question is tagged as Django but Twig is a PHP template engine?

Comment: Wow!!!!! Till this date I thought, django uses twig template... Now, I know. Django uses Django template language (DTL) . Thank you!!! You could answer the question as I got it, so that anyone with same thought will get help.